# Sails.js res.json not returning deep properties when using nested-pop

Tags: javascript, json, sails.js

I have this code to get some stock data with deep nested associations by using [nested-pop](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nested-pop):

```
Stock.find({limit:100, sort:'name ASC'})
  .populate('scans', {limit:1,sort:'createdAt DESC'})
  .then((stocks) => {
    return nestedPop(stocks, {
      scans: ['values']
    })
  }).then(stocks => {
    console.log(stocks[0].scans[0]);
    res.json(stocks);
  })
```

**In the server console the scan is logged and the *values* array is printed. But res.json returns the stocks with scans that are all missing the *values* array.**

Expected output:

```
[{
  id: 1,
  scans: [
    {
      id: 1,
      values: [
        {
          id: 1,
          value: 0.5,
          type: 1
        },
        ...
      ]
    }
  ]
}, ...]
```

The returned output:

```
[{
  id: 1,
  scans: [
    {
      id: 1,
    }
  ]
}, ...]
```

The error doesn't seem to be related to the depth of the object, because I tested it with some deeper test object and everything was returned. I just don't understand how this is not returned by res.json if **it's there**.

**UPDATE:**

I made other tests now and found out that both, `.toObject` and `.toJSON` called on a single stock cause the values to disappear on the server side. And because `res.json` is calling `.toJSON` on the passed objects it also doesn't appear in the browser.

Comment: Have you overridden the `.toJSON` method of any of your models? I think those are auto-called by `res.json`.

Comment: No I haven’t overridden .toJSON.

Comment: you dont need to override, try to call `.toObject()` on the object before u send it back to the user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nestedPop is returning values that can not be parsed correctly by `.toJSON`, because they are already converted. 
I solved the problem by converting all stocks before I pass them into nestedPop, so the working code is:

```
Stock.find({limit:100, sort:'name ASC'})
  .populate('scans', {limit:1,sort:'createdAt DESC'})
  .then((stocks) => {
    stocks = stocks.map((s) => s.toJSON());
    return nestedPop(stocks, {
      scans: ['values']
    })
  }).then(stocks => {
    console.log(stocks[0].scans[0]);
    res.json(stocks);
  })
```

Now everything is logged on the server side AND passed to browser.